# Conventional way to wait for Appium XML to inflate into view hierarchy

Tags: appium-ios, appium-android

Appium XML seems to take time to "inflate" into a complete view hierarchy, around ~200 milliseconds in my experience, and often the findViewBy() does not find the view unless the thread is instructed to sleep, or the code is re-executed until the NoSuchWebElement exception is no longer thrown.

Is there a conventional way wait for the entire appium XML layout to complete "inflation" without sleeping the thread or testing for the NoSuchWebElement?

Like shouldn't UI automator or XCUITest tell Appium when the  view hierarchy has completed inflation? All approaches to waiting for view inflation seem hacky to me.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is support for adding a timeout when polling for an element in the view hierarchy.

http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/session/timeouts/implicit-wait/

Apparently there are also more advanced conditions such as waiting for all elements of a given view class to be visible, and so on.

https://seleniumjava.com/2016/04/05/the-beginners-guide-to-explicit-waits/